# Is there a standard name for the boundary of a cube?

Tags: geometry, terminology, convention

A distinction is commonly made between a ball (solid) and a sphere (the boundary of a ball). This distinction is made in other dimensions as well (e.g. circle versus disc, in 2D).

From what I've seen trying to research this online, the word "cube" is usually used to refer to the soild. Is there any standard name for just the boundary of a cube? The only thing that came to mind was "box" but that both doesn't seem to be a standard term, and might intuitively refer to the boundary of any rectangular prism.

(My question extends to squares as well, i.e. is there a standard name for just the boundary of a square? And a similar question could be asked in reverse about the torus, where that name is usual used to refer to only the boundary.)

If there is no standard name, my follow-up question would be: *why* do we have distinct names for spheres and balls, but not other common solids? Just historical accident? (Is the distinction made in languages other than English?)

Comment: For the 2D case, ["lamina"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lamina.html) seems to be a general name for the filled region, so maybe circle is to disk as square is to ... square lamina?

Comment: The sphere/ball distinction must surely be made in all languages by mathematicians that wish to do the same kind of math that other mathematicians are doing. I am sure that some languages make the distinction more gracefully than others.

Comment: How about "the boundary of a cube"?

Comment: There's also correspondence with the [$L^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#/media/File:Vector-p-Norms_qtl1.svg) and [$L^\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_norm) norms in $\Bbb R^2$. Perhaps there's literature out there focusing on $\Bbb R^3$ that has proposed or uses standard (if not well-known) terminology?

Comment: Maybe the surface of the cube?

Comment: "surface of a cube" is pretty common and unambiguous and clear ("boundary of a cube" seems a little weird to me but ... that's just personal taste.)  I'm not sure it's universally accepted that we *do* us sphere to specifically mean the surface.  I think in a lot of cases people might (perhaps incorrectly) refer to a sphere as the solid and be understood.  I think the reason we talk of spheres as surfaces is that in Topology we can have flat 2D space (a plane) and curved 2D space-- ultimately a surface of a sphere (even though we seldom step back to look at it from a 3D perspective).

Comment: @fleablood _colloquially_, it's certainly common for people to mean $D^3=\{\mathbf{r}\in\mathbb{R}^3:\|\mathbf{r}\|\leq1\}$ when they say "sphere". But in the mathematical disciplines that deal with these a lot, the convention is actually very clear that $D^3$ is a _ball_ and only $S^2 = \partial D^3$ is a sphere.

Comment: @leftaroundabout exactly! I was only talking about the colloquial use of the word "sphere" and in disciplines where this distinction is *not* a focus.

Comment: Well, a topologist would refer to it as a sphere... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of no standard names for those boundaries.

Mathematicians give the sphere and ball those distinctive names because they often want to discuss both in the same context.

The boundary of the cube comes up less often. In some contexts it's the two skeleton. The one skeleton is the set of edges.

To refer to a torus together with its interior you would say "solid torus".

Comment: A couple days on and seeing nobody claiming any standard name, I'll accept this answer.  Out of curiosity, would you mind sharing an example of a context where both spheres and balls come up together and distinguishing them is important?

Comment: In topology, balls have trivial homotopy but the homotopy of spheres is interesting and important: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to the **faces** of a cube (or other polyhedron).

Comment: Not really the same thing though. The boundary of the cube is the union of the faces, but "the faces" are a collection of individual squares.